# Type 3 font is not embeded

Tags: fonts

I am using `bbm` Package for required `mathbbmss` font.

The problem is `Type1 font and subset fonts` are Embedded successfully in PDF properties (For Ex: CMMI8 (Embedded subset)).  But "Type 3 font F33" font is not Embedded successfully as like Type 1 font.

I will explain the problem below mentioned Two figures.

[image: Marked Type 3 font is not embedded]

The below mentioned Figure is explain the PDF properties

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{bbm}
\begin{document}
\def\Ind#1{{\mathbbmss 1}_{_{\scriptstyle #1}}}

\def\MathInd#1{{\mathbb 1}_{_{\scriptstyle #1}}}

Notation One $\Ind{A}$ 

Notation Two $\MathInd{A}$ 

\end{document}
```

My updmap.cfg is `pdftexDownloadBase14 true` the option "true" is enabled.

How to `embedded subset` the type3 font. Please advice.

Comment: The font is embedded but it is a bitmap font.

Comment: Yep --- embedded yes, subset no. Is it possible to subset a Type3 (bitmap) font?

Comment: OK. I will check.

Comment: You should be aware that bitmap fonts are notorious for looking awful in certain popular PDF viewers. Moreover, bitmap fonts do not scale smoothly e.g. if you zoom (even if a less popular viewer), they will look jagged. If you are sending the PDF elsewhere, you would be well advised to avoid these fonts and stick to scalable varieties if at all possible. If you are printing, this is probably not a problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How did you recognized that Type 3 font is indeed embedded? (as it is not mentioned exclusively beside the font)